# snapshot of FutureBuilder is null in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, class, snapshot, flutter-futurebuilder

this code uses data.dart class but gets snapshot.data as null, when I implement the second code in dart code with a simple main function this error doesnt arise. how to avoid snapshot getting null.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/data.dart';

void main() {
   getStudents();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget{
 const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Android Expert'),),
      body:FutureBuilder<List<StudentData>?>(future: getStudents(), builder:(context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(height: 84, color: Colors.red, margin:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 4, 8, 4));
            },
          );
        }
        else{
          return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
      },)
    ); 
  }
}
```

data.dart class is the following. In this code JSON information is read and pass to a real student. an error that arise in debug console is Error: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: XMLHttpRequest error.

```
    import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
    
    class StudentData{
      final int id;
      final String firstName;
      final String lastName;
      final String course;
      final int score;
      final String createdAt;
      final String updatedAt;
    
      StudentData(this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.course, this.score,
      this.createdAt, this.updatedAt);
  StudentData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        firstName = json['first_name'],
        lastName = json['last_name'],
        course = json['course'],
        score = json['score'],
        createdAt = json['created_at'],
        updatedAt = json['created_at'];
    }
    
    class HttpClient{
      static Dio instance=Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: 'http://expertdevelopers.ir/api/v1/'));
    }
    
    Future<List<StudentData>?> getStudents()async{
      final response=await HttpClient.instance.get('experts/student');
    
      final List<StudentData> students=[];
      if (response.data is List<dynamic>){
        (response.data as List<dynamic>).forEach((element) {
          students.add(StudentData.fromJson(element));
        });
      }
      //print(students.toString());
      return students;
    }
```

Comment: give it initialData

Comment: Data is passed in getStudents function and nothing is wrong